# slow startup, failed to connect to lvmetad

Tags: 18.04, lvm, lvmcache

Ubuntu 18.04 after install seems to be doing quite OK, but the startup is *slow*. It's almost minute to get to "cryptluks screen", to enter pass to decrypt lvm partition. I noticed unknown error to me, so maybe it can be related?

```
Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
volume group crypt not found
Cannot process volume group crypt

Please unlock disk ...
```

but once I log in, yes I'm able to log eventually, I can do:

```
sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               crypt
...
```

questions:

1. could this be cause of really slow boot time
2. what's wrong with lvmetad?